# fullScreenControl fullScreenControlOptions in Googlemap API V3.22 for streetview

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Googlemap introduced `fullScreenControl`options in V3.22.

[v322-controls-diff](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v322-controls-diff)

When I tried to disable the `fullScreenControl` by settings it to `false` in `google.maps.MapOptions`, it is not working. I can successully control all the others like `panControl`, `zoomControl`, but this one doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you set it to true and set something in the `fullScreenControlOptions`, does that work?  What does your code look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At moment it seems not to work. This is a way you can hide the fullscreen element with css:

```
.gm-style > div:nth-child(10){
 display:none;
}
```

For new version:

```
.gm-style > div:nth-child(6){
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: .gm-style > div:nth-child(6){
 display:none;
}

Answer (score 1):

Since 18 January 2016 release, have to be this to make it work:

```
.gm-fullscreen-control {
  display: none;
}
```

The Googlemap's documentation claims that, `The full-screen control for Street View is enabled by default. You can disable it via StreetViewPanoramaOptions and configure it using the FullscreenControlOptions. Its default position is now RIGHT_TOP`. [releases](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

`fullscreenControl`  not `fullScreenControl`

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a minor flaw in the API at this moment. I´ve made some tests and was also unable to remove the full screen control with the fullScreenControlOptions field, as specified in the documentation.

The full screen control is displayed even if you set the disableDefaultUI to true.

I know this may not be the better way to get rid of the element, but you can do something like:

```js
var FULL_SCREEN_CONTROL_STYLE = {
 width: '25px',
 height: '25px',
 top: '0px',
 right: '0px',
 position: 'absolute',
 overflow: 'hidden'
};

var children = panorama.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i<children.length; i++) {

 var current = children[i];
  
 var match = true;
 
 for (var k in FULL_SCREEN_CONTROL_STYLE) {
  if (current.style[k] != FULL_SCREEN_CONTROL_STYLE[k]) {
   match = false;
  }
 }
 
 if (match) { // THIS IS OUR ELEMENT
  current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
 }
 
}
```